# October Fixed text after 'title'

Tags: octobercms

I guess it has to be easy but I do not know how to do it. I wanna put a fixed test after page title. Something like 'title' | by Stamford

I am working on October CMS.

Thanks

```
function onStart() {  
    $slug = $this->param('slug');   
    $this['entry'] = \Shifta\Admin\Models\Master::where('slug', $slug)->first();      
    $this['fallback_color'] = '#3789d1';     
}

function onEnd() {   
    $this->page->title = $this['entry']->title;   
    $this->page->meta_description = $this['entry']->seo_description;   
}
```

Comment: `$this->page->title = $this['entry']->title . ' | by Stamford';` you can do something like this ?

Comment: Thanks. It works

Comment: good to hear that .. :)